# '__kernel' does not name a type

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, kernel, opencl

I am trying to compile the code found here: http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-resources/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/

I am compiling it with the command:

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -lm -lOpenCL -g -Wno-unknown-pragmas foo.cpp -o foo
```

The portion of the code causing issues is this:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
 __constant char hw[] = "Hello World\n";

 __kernel void hello(__global char * out) {
      size_t tid = get_global_id(0);
      out[tid] = hw[tid];
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
foo.cpp:105:2: error: ‘__constant’ does not name a type
  __constant char hw[] = "Hello World\n";

foo.cpp:107:2: error: ‘__kernel’ does not name a type
  __kernel void hello(__global char * out) {
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? The headers are exactly as they are on the link.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile OpenCL code as native code (to run on your CPU). As far as I can tell, gcc doesn't recognise opencl as a language. You need an opencl compiler to compile the code. Clang does understand opencl, but you still can't compile it as a native application without further support in form of a runtime library. The normal way to use OpenCL is to use clCreateProgramFromSource(), clBuildProgram(), clCreateKernel() and clEnqueueNDRange() [with some boilerplate before/after]

Comment: @MatsPetersson is correct (and should submit that as an answer)

Comment: I am not attempting to compile with GCC as the link suggested. I am using g++ with -lOpenCl which should he working which is why I'm confused... The other opencl function calls are all find it's only the declaration of the kernel method that is an issue

Comment: g++  is the gcc C++ variant. As my answer describes below, the kernel is compiled from your OpenCL host code, using clCreateProgramWithSource or something like it. The AMD tools most likely also has an offline compiler that you can use to create a binary, which can then be loaded with clCreateProgramWithBinary, but I'm pretty sure that's not going to help you much. I work with OpenCL at ARM, so don't know the intimate details of the AMD solution, but I expect it bears a lot of similarity with the ARM product offering.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile OpenCL code like that (without a fair bit more supporting infrastructure, such as an OpenCL-capable compiler and library for the OpenCL functionality - Clang is capable of compiling OpenCL for x86, but then complains about not having the supprting libraries when it tries to link things).

The typical OpenCL application will look something like this:

```
// Get platform, device and context - this is about 10-20 lines of "boilerplate" code. 
const char* source = "... your code goes here ...";
// But you could of course read it from a file, for example!
cl_int err;
clProgram prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, NULL, &err);
err = clBuildProgram(prog, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
cl_kernel kern = clCreateKernel(prog, "hello", &err);
cl_mem out = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 100, NULL, err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(out), out);
size_t range = 1;
cl_command_queue queue = cl_create_command_queue( ... );
cl_event event;
err = clEnqueueNDRange(queue, kern, 1, NULL, &size, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
clFlush(queue);
clWaitForEvent(event);
// Lots of lines of code to release everything.
```

[I have just hand-written the above lines - I don't have a CL environment at home, so I can't check it - it shows the general principle, and I skipped quite a bit of setup/teardown code - and of course, error checking should be done for every call to the OpenCL library, since it's often easy to get it a tad wrong and get an error back, which then leads to the next step crashing/going wrong]

There are object-oriented variants, which allows you to avoid some of the cleanup (the destructor does it for you), but since I have only written such code a few times [vs. many times with the basic C version shown above], I'd have to go through the docs or look at the "OpenCL C++ bindings card" that I have at work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on the same tutorial. Here is my attempt to overcome it.

The confusing part of that tutorial is where it gives you the OpenCL code without explicitly telling you to place that code in a file named "lesson1_kernel.cl"

I figured this out because earlier in the tutorial, native code reads this file:

```
std::ifstream file("lesson1_kernels.cl");
checkErr(file.is_open() ? CL_SUCCESS:-1, "lesson1_kernel.cl");
std::string prog(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
cl::Program::Sources source(
    1,
    std::make_pair(prog.c_str(), prog.length()+1));
```

All of the previous "native code" in that tutorial belongs in the file that you will be compiling.  Per the tutorial's instructions, the native code belongs in a file named "lesson1.cpp"

```
gcc –o hello_world –Ipath-OpenCL-include –Lpath-OpenCL-libdir lesson1.cpp –lOpenCL
```

I didn't want to create a new lesson1_kernels.cl file for a simple one-off script like this, so I instead put all the OpenCL code into a string and created the cl::Program::Sources object with that string using the appropriate escape characters:

```
const std::string openCLCode("#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable\n__constant char hw[] = \"Hello World\\n\";\n__kernel void hello(__global char * out) \n\n{\n  size_t tid = get_global_id(0);\n  out[tid] = hw[tid];\n}\n");
```

and:

```
cl::Program::Sources source(
    1,
    std::make_pair(openCLCode.c_str(), openCLCode.length()+1));
cl::Program program(context, source);
```

Once I did that I was able to compile and run the program with no further issues.  Thank you theNoobProgrammer for posting my issue, and thank you Matts Petersson for helping me solve it without significantly modifying the tutorial code.